# Wall too thin for outlet box?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am trying to install a small metal utility box in the corner of my living room for internet.

I found a stud, drilled a hole beside it to see what surprises lay hidden in that wall, and noticed that there isn't enough depth in there for the utility box. I can put my finger in a little less than 2 inches before I hit another surface.

There is a thin brown paper-like thing (I am a complete amateur so I have no idea what it is, fireproofing?), and some other surface behind that. The wood doesn't look like a standard stud at all.

Here are some pics:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is already an outlet on this wall, so someone managed to do this. Behind this wall is the outside. Should I keep drilling and pierce the second surface? Should I put the utility box somewhere else?

Comment: One thing to make your life easier: you don't need that whole utility box. Low voltage wiring like this can be installed with a low voltage ring, which is much shallower. Example here: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-1-Gang-Non-Metallic-Low-Voltage-Old-Work-Bracket-SC100RR/100160916

Comment: Wow, thanks! Do these low voltage rings need to be attached to a stud or can I just put them anywhere in the drywall?

Comment: @KMJ answers go down there... That's _exactly_ what I was going to put up as an answer.

Comment: Outside wooden walls should be at least 3.5 inches deep.  They should also have insulation which might have paper on it.

Comment: @PaulG they are designed as "old work" - they have little wings that will flip out when you turn the screws and clamp themselves to the drywall. They can go anywhere.

Comment: @FreeMan didn't put it as an answer because I didn't address the rather important 'should I keep drilling?' part of the question, which I think is critical to properly answering this one. If it's still sitting without a full answer later maybe I'll put one together with a wall cross-section.

Comment: Behind this wall is *at least one more wythe of brick*. They used hammer and a cold chisel, or an impact hammer to make a relief.

Comment: It's possible this is a furred-out wall, and what you see inside the hole is the actual/original wall behind it. The power outlet's box could be recessed into the true wall if that's the case.  That doesn't really impact your solution, just food for thought.

Answer (score 6):

Fortunately, for low-voltage (Ethernet, phone, coax, etc.) you don't need to use a full box. Use a [box eliminator](https://amzn.to/3FblpQS):

[image]

This is a metal one via Amazon (better online images than at Home Depot). There are also plastic varieties, and while I prefer metal, most of the usual "metal boxes are better than plastic" issues simply do not apply to low voltage, so pick whatever type works best for you.

Comment: And some of them are easy to use for old work with ears that pop out via screws to hold them in place.  Might not be as robust as metal, but easy to install.

Comment: And if you don't have enough depth for that box eliminator ring either, they make surface mount boxes for phone/network connections. Some of those ends up taking up less space than a cable sticking out perpendicular to the wall.